# Is there a constructor interface for a struct type?

Tags: go, constructor

In golang, say I have a type that needs some setup done on it before use beyond just setting default values. ex:

```
type dice struct {
    input   string
    count   int
    sides   int
    result  int
}

func (d *dice) Roll() {
    //initialize random seed
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < d.count; i++ {
        d.result = d.result + rand.Intn(d.sides)+1)
    }
}
```

Simple example but say if I wanted to have d.Roll() called automatically when creating an instance of the 'dice' type is there a way to do that? More in line with the issue I'm trying to solve, say I wanted the rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano()) bits to be called automatically before I call Roll() is there an idiomatic golang way to do this?

Basically "How do you handle constructor functionality in golang?" is my question. Is there an interface for this I can add?

Answer (score 1):

No, Go doesn't provide this kind of interface. You just can't use a constructor like you would do in C++ by example.

The current idiom is to create a function

```
NewX(args...) X // or *X
```

in which you can setup your struct as you want. In your case, it could look like this:

```
func NewDice() dice {
  var d dice
  d.Roll()
  return d
}
```

Comment: @RyanM Thank you. By the way if I get it right, you will call `rand.Seed()` each time a `dice` is created. This could lead to some unexpected behavior, [this question about seeding properly the random generator in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321133/golang-random-number-generator-how-to-seed-properly) could be worth reading.

Comment: Yeah I have a stackoverflow code review page where they brought up the same thing (though the person there didn't actually explain why it was a bad idea so thanks for that). I'm looking at using crypto/rand instead, the docs for that just aren't as good so I'm having to dig.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. But the common, and I would say idiomatic, thing to do is to put a `func NewDice() dice` in your package and then you can just call it to get an instance. Do your set up there. It serves the same purpose as a constructor. It's pretty common to have package level methods like `NewMyType` that do initilization and return and instance.