# Generating fixed length random number in Go lang

Tags: go, random

I need to generate an unique random number in Golang. I have a simple ruby code for it:

```
(0...16).map { rand(10).to_s }.join
```

So, effectively i need to generate a number of length 16 where each digit is randomly picked up from [0-9]. I did not understand how random.Intn(n) function can help me. Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Exactly the same way? Generate 16 digits and join them. Hint (if you actually need a number not a string): `v = v * 10 + randomDigit`

Comment: It's probably more efficient (in both Go and Ruby) to just generate a single random number between 0 and 1*10ˆ16-1.

Comment: Also for a fast general solution (when you need not just digits and / or you need longer than what fits into an `int64`), see [How to generate a random string of a fixed length in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892120/how-to-generate-a-random-string-of-a-fixed-length-in-golang/31832326#31832326)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is:

```
s := ""
for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
    s += (string)(rand.Intn(10) + 48)
}
```

48 is the ascii value for `0`.

Or by using @Flimzy's more efficient suggestion:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%016d", rand.Int63n(1e16))
```

where `"%016d"` will help pad the number with zeros.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to seed that random in some form?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you surely need to [seed](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed).  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321133/golang-random-number-generator-how-to-seed-properly for that.