# How to save the clustering model using go?

Tags: go, cluster-analysis, k-means

I wrote a clustering algorithm for k means using go, and I want to save that model so that it can run next time using that saved information.

I want to ask how to go about it. Some direction or some library or package would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Try including the work which you have done until now. Elaborate your problem to get detailed explanations.

Comment: I think you need to set a random seed to get reproducible results. See Q [Golang random number generator how to seed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321133/golang-random-number-generator-how-to-seed-properly)  (from 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Seriously? You need a "package" to save k vectors?

Just **save the vectors yourself**, and rather avoid adding too many dependencies that can break.

Comment: i was actually confused about what information do i need to save , only centers or anyother?

Comment: Just think through what the algorithm does... Easier than Googling for a library.