# Math/Rand in GoLang

Tags: go, math, random

hello **Golang** devs I am learning golang and I am using the **Math/Rand** package. I am curious why I am getting the same result on:

```
// always returning 81

 rand.Intn(100)
```

Comment: [Properly setting seed Random Number Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321133/how-to-properly-seed-random-number-generator/12321192#12321192)

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [`math/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/) says:

> Top-level functions, such as Float64 and Int, use a default shared Source that produces a deterministic [fixed] sequence of values each time a program is run. Use the Seed function to initialize the default Source if different behavior is required for each run.