# rand.Seed(SEED) is deprecated, how to use NewRand(NewSeed( ) )?

Tags: go

I am studying go just now.

I an example I've this line

```
rand.Seed(SEED)
```

But the vscode extension about go is telling me

> rand.Seed has been deprecated since Go 1.20 and an alternative has been available since Go 1.0: Programs that call Seed and then expect a specific sequence of results from the global random source (using functions such as Int) can be broken when a dependency changes how much it consumes from the global random source. To avoid such breakages, programs that need a specific result sequence should use NewRand(NewSource(seed)) to obtain a random generator that other packages cannot access.  (SA1019)

I cannot understand how to use `NewRand(NewSource(seed))` as suggested.

I found doc about NewSource https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand#NewSource

But there is not doc about a `NewRand` function

What is the new reccomended equivalent of `rand.Seed(SEED)` ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [Go 1.20 Seed documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand@go1.20#Seed) has a typo. Use `rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))` as described in the [latest documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/math/rand@master#Seed) and the [Go 1.20 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20).

Create the random source and use methods on the source instead of calling the package functions:

```
  r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
  fmt.Println(r.Uint64())
  fmt.Println(r.Uint64())
```

Comment: Ok, but how to use it? This returns a rand.Random oject, so must we use it instead of using rand.random() ?

Comment: @realtebo Yes, call methods on the *rand.Random instead of calling the package functions.

Comment: It appears that the random generator will be automatically seeded at startup now - see VonC's answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74077488

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example demonstrating how to generate random numbers between 1 and 15 in Go version 1.20 or newer:

```
// Create a new random number generator with a custom seed (e.g., current time)
source := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
rng := rand.New(source)

// Generate a random number of minutes between 1 and 15
randomMinutes := rng.Intn(15) + 1
```